# cannot update component from inside overlaypanel inside datatable primefaces

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces, updating

I want to update one component from another inside `p:overlayPanel` inside `p:datatable`

here is the code :

```
    <p:tabView id="monpanel">
<p:tab id="tab1" title=".....">
.....
</p:tab>
<p:tab id="tab2" title=".....">
.....
</p:tab>
<p:tab id="tab3" title="Stock et fournisseurs">

                    <h:panelGrid>
                        <h:outputLabel value="Stock : "
                            style="text-decoration: underline;font-weight: 900;" />

                        <p:commandButton id="carBtn" value="Ajouter" type="button" />
                        <p:outputLabel id="nombref"
                            value="#{articlesMB.NBF} fournisseurs séléctionnés." />

                        <p:overlayPanel appendToBody="true"  widgetVar="overlayp"
                            id="carPanel" for="carBtn" hideEffect="fade" dynamic="true">
                            <p:dataTable id="table" var="car" rowKey="#{car.fournisseurId}"
                                value="#{articlesMB.listfournisseurs}"
                                selection="#{articlesMB.selectedFournisseurs}" rows="10"
                                paginator="true">


                                <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:20px" />
                                <p:column headerText="Id">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{car.fournisseurId}" />
                                </p:column>

                                <p:column headerText="Nom">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{car.personne.nom}" />
                                </p:column>
                                <f:facet name="footer">
                                    <p:commandButton id="multiViewButton" value="View"
                                        icon="ui-icon-search" update=":nombref"
                                        oncomplete="multiCarDialog.show()" />
                                </f:facet>


                            </p:dataTable>
                        </p:overlayPanel>
                        </p:tab>
                        <p:tabview>
```

I tested `update=":nombref"`  and `update="monpanel:nombref"` and `update=":monpanel:nombref"` but always I have this error :

```
    com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback visit
GRAVE: javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find component with identifier ":nombref" referenced from "monpanel:table:multiViewButton".
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: You try: update=":#{p:component('nombref')}"

Comment: unfortunetly, same error, :(

Comment: @RongNK, is it possible to chat with you

Comment: @simonTifo Open your browser's developer settings find the `nombref` component and it's generated ID can be different, so you should give the exact client ID when you are updating it.

Comment: You need to try @Ömer Faruk Almalı's suggestion.

Comment: I already tried it, I find : `monpanel:nombref` but when I update it from inside the overlaypanel inside datatable , the error

Comment: May be you set dynamic="true" for tabView ?

Comment: no I don't set any attribute